# i need help to generate a sequence numbers in the for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, numbers, sequence

i need help to generate a sequence numbers in the `for loop` i have code but it is not working properly as i want to do it is generating random numbers?

if `for loop` reached to the `999` then automatically how to addition after for loop reached to the `999` for loop should be addition like this `999+1=1000+1=10001`?

**i want script generate number like this**

```
500,501,502,503,....so on till 999
```

**here my code**

```
$numbers = range(500, 999);
foreach ($numbers as $i) {
echo $say = str_pad($i, 5, "0",  STR_PAD_LEFT).'<br>';
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `range(500, 999)`...

Comment: And if you want a set display size with leading zeroes, use str_pad() or sprintf() rather than that convoluted series of `if` statements

Comment: Please rephrase your question. You are talking about random numbers at some point, but don't tell us what role those should play in what you are doing. And why should the for loop start with 500 again when it reached 999? That would make it infinite.

Comment: @TillHelge you right but i want to generate order numbers on the email to provide customer's if `for loop` reached to the finish point then what will happened? how will customer's get order numbers after reached to the `999`?

Comment: what you mean by reaches to `999`?

Comment: @6339 my script like this `500,501,502,503,....so on till 999` if for loop reached to the `999 number` then sequence numbers will stop then how will customer's get order numbers after stop?

Comment: When you create random numbers you will never "reach" 999. Using `rand()` doesn't mean that a number can be picked only once. It might happen that several times in a row 999 is picked and sometimes 999 will not be picked at all for a long time. Maybe it would be better if you would explain what you want to do.

Comment: @TillHelge can you tell how to additional after `999+1=1000+1=10001`??? like this???

Comment: I honestly have no clue what you are talking about. Take some time, write up exactly and in detail what you want to achieve...then update your question. With these short comments and questions you will never get a proper solution.

Comment: @TillHelge sorry to confused you i want to do after for loop reached to the `999` then automatically add like this `999+1=1000+1=10001`?

Comment: Why do you need a random number in the first place? Why don't give the first customer number 1, 2 to the second and so on? And why start at 500 or the 999 limit?

Comment: And I repeat it again: Don't tell us what you want the script to do...tell us what you need. Maybe we can find a solution this way. Because you talking about your code apparently doesn't work.

Comment: @TillHelge brother now my script is `$numbers = range(500, 999);
foreach ($numbers as $i) { echo $say = str_pad($i, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).'<br>'; }` now it want add `after loop reached to the `999` then it will be start addition 999+1=1000+1=10001?

Comment: This is getting weirder. So you want this sequence: 999,1000,10001? what happens after 10009? it's 100010 or 10010?

Comment: @Borgtex yes exactly i want like this `999,1000,10001  and so ... on`? now my script is like this $numbers = range(500, 999); foreach ($numbers as $i) { echo $say = str_pad($i, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).'<br>'; }

Comment: Why do you use `range(500,999)` if you want it to continue beyond `999`? Just put the number you want as last number in there.

Answer (score 3):

Use a for loop with your range. And use [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/str-pad)

```
for ($i = 500; $i < 1000; $i++) {
     $say = str_pad($i, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

And with [`range()`](http://php.net/range):

```
$numbers = range(500, 999);
foreach ($numbers as $i) {
     $say = str_pad($i, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Edit:
It is not clear to me how and why you want to start at 500 again when reaching 999, but you could wrap the above in:

```
while (true) {
    // One of the above solutions
}
```

WARNING: the above will create an infinit loop!

Try something like this:

```
$h = 0;
while ($h < 10) {
    // One of the above solutions
    $h++
}
```

or

```
for ($h = 0; $h < 10; $h++) {
    // One of the above solutions
}
```

Comment: it is working now but how do i automatically start with `500` if loop reached to the `999`?

Comment: It is not clear to me how and why you want to start at 500 again when reaching 999, so I provided some basic solutions of which you should pick the one closest to your needs...

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$num=rand(500, 999);
for ($i = 500; $i <=$num ; $i++) {
    echo str_pad($i,5,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Comment: how do i automatically start with 500 if loop reached to the 999?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
    $seed=rand(500, 999);

    for ($i = 0; $i <500 ; $i++)
    {           
       $num=500+($seed+$i)%500;
       $say = str_pad($num,5,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
```